# Tomcat Datasource configuration Connection timeout and Max Active to Idle connection ratio

Tags: java, database, tomcat, jdbc

I am having a web application which is load balanced on four servers. These three servers connect to common database with max connections setup to 600.

My Current database pool configuration in tomcat is as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/AppDB"
                          auth="Container"
                          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          maxActive="100"
                          maxIdle="30"
                          maxWait="10000"
                          removeAbandoned ="true"
                          removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
                          testOnBorrow="true"
                          validationQuery="select 1"
                          logAbandoned ="true"
                          username="username"
                          password="password"
                          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                          url="dbconnectionurl"
                 />
```

But this configuration gives Exception: `Connection Timeout : Waiting for Idle Object.`

I have monitored database server, my effective utilization of connections is 350 only.

If I calculate it backwards, I have total 400 connections used actively. This gives me 200 extra database connections available from DB.

Hence, I am not able to understand why this Exception is coming.

Can anybody suggest a better configuration ? 
What should be the ideal ratio of `maxActive` and `maxIdle` ?

UPDATE:

I found a related link: 
[There are not enough idle connections in Tomcat JDBC pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735429/there-are-not-enough-idle-connections-in-tomcat-jdbc-pool?rq=1)

But I can not risk setting maxIdle or MaxActive to -1(INFINITE) because I have multiple instances running, and it might make uneven distribution of connections. This may cause one instance to perform nicely and other may fail due to lack of connections.

Answer (score 5):

First off, `maxIdle` doesn't have anything to do with your problem, as this only defines how many connections are kept in the pool that are not actively used - excess connections will be dropped. To illustrate this: imagine that at *t1* 80 connections are in use; at *t2* only 30 connections are still in use, meaning 50 connections are put back into the pool. The `maxIdle` setting of 30 now causes the pool to close 20 of the 50 idle connections.
Now if at *t3* 50 connections are in use again, the "idle pool" would contain only 10 connections. The number of connections in the idle pool is not actively increased!

To make that clear: `maxActive` is the maximum number of connections the pool provides. `maxIdle` does not add another bunch of connections on top of that; it is just a means to keep around a number of connections for the base load, speeding up the connection usage (if `maxIdle` would be 0, each connection returned to the pool would be closed, thwarting the idea of a connection pool).

To suggest a proper ratio for your case is kind of hard, as it depends on the load curve your application has to face. But for the problem you are facing (the pool does not return an idle, i.e. "free" connection), it wouldn't matter if you'd set it to `-1`, as the pool is simply exhausted.

So to fix your problem, you either need to increase `maxActive` or you need to find ways to use the connections more efficiently.

Comment: Since we have limited number of connections from database, setting up a high value of maxIdle on low traffic may also be a bad decision overall. Due to this reason I was worried about maxIdle parameter. However, I think that you have correctly pointed out that Pool is exhausted hence maxActive is real culprit here.

Comment: If you refrain from defining a high value for `maxIdle`, you may set `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` to something like 15 minutes. This will help you to eventually decrease the number of open connections to a minimum during low traffic, whilst still profiting from idle connections being available during times of high, but erratic traffic.

Comment: As of now, I have increased number of Active connections. If this still gives problem, I will add above too. Thanks.

Comment: If with "above" you mean `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` etc. - this won't help you. It really is a problem of either your app needing more available connections at the database side or you you make rather inefficient use of your connections and get rid of that...